# IETE journal of Research latex template

Tags: journal-publishing

Does anyone have IETE journal of Research latex template. I didnt find any latex template. How do i use latex template to follow their guidelines. 
Please help.

Comment: Have you asked the publisher if they have such a template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For submission to IETE journal of Research you need only the `.pdf` file. So you can use the standard `article` class. Once your paper is accepted for publication the rest of the things (style requirements) will be taken care by the editorial office.

But if you want to use the `LaTeX template`, then I have edited a `.cls` file to satisfy most of the requirements of the `IETE journal of Research` styles. Put both the `IETEJR.cls` and the `template.tex` in a folder and prepare you paper.

**template.tex**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IETEJR}
\begin{document}

\title{Template for submission of papers to IETE Journal of Research}
\author{ First A. Author, Second B. Author, Jr., and Third C. Author\\
\vspace*{0.05em}\\\small F. A. Author is with the National Institute of Standards and Technology,\\\small Boulder, CO 80305 USA (corresponding author to provide phone: 303-555-5555;\\\small fax: 303-555-5555; e-mail: author@ boulder.nist.gov). \\
    \small S. B. Author, Jr., was with Rice University, Houston, TX 77005 USA.\\\small He is now with the Department of Physics, Colorado State University,\\\small Fort Collins, CO 80523 USA (e-mail: author@lamar.colostate.edu).\\
    \small T. C. Author is with the Electrical Engineering Department,\\\small University of Colorado, Boulder, CO 80309 USA, on leave from the \\\small National Research Institute for Metals,\\\small Tsukuba, Japan (e-mail: author@nrim.go.jp).}

\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    Fill the text from your manuscript in different sections.   ...
    \end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
About six to fifteen key words or phrases in alphabetical order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, visit http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani_prod/keywrd98.txt
\end{keywords}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{INTRODUCTION}

Fill the text from your manuscript
\section{SECTION TWO}
\subsection{Sub-section Head Style}
Fill the text from your manuscript
\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Fill the text from your manuscript

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Fill the text from your manuscript in different sections. 
\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Fill the text from your manuscript in different sections. 


\section{CONCLUSION}
The conclusion goes here.



%\appendices
\section{Proof of the First Zonklar Equation}
Appendix one text goes here.

\section{}
Appendix two text goes here.


% use section* for acknowledgement
\section*{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}


The authors would like to thank...
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{1}R. Roy, and T. Kailath, “ESPRIT\_estimation of signal parameters via rotational invariance techniques,” IEEE Trans. Acoust. Speech Signal Process, Vol. 37, no. 7, pp. 984-95, Jul. 1989.
\bibitem{2}   V. Wowk, Machinery Vibration, Measurement and Analysis. New York: McGraw-Hill, 1991.
\bibitem{3}   Case Western Reserve University Bearing Data Center. Available: http://csegroups.case.edu/bearingdatacenter/pa\\ges/downloaddata-file, accessed Apr. 2013.
\bibitem{4} B. Li, M.-Y. Chow, Y. Tipsuwan, and J. C. Hung, “Neural network based motor rolling bearing fault diagnosis,” IEEE Trans. Ind. Electron.,Vol. 47, no. 5, pp. 1060\_9, Oct. 2000.
\bibitem{5} J. Altmann, and J. Mathew, “Multiple band-pass autoregressive demodulation for rolling element bearing fault diagnosis,” Mech. Syst. Signal Process., Vol. 15, no. 5, pp. 963\_77, Sep. 2001.
\bibitem{6} B. Samanta, and K. R. Al-Balushi, “Artificial neural network based fault diagnostics of rolling element bearings using time domain features,” Mech. Syst. Signal Process., Vol. 17, no. 2, pp. 317\_28, Mar. 2003.
\bibitem{7} B. S. Yang, T. Han, and J. L. An, “ART\_KOHONEN neural network for fault diagnosis of rotating machinery,” Mech. Syst. Signal Process., Vol. 18, no. 3, pp. 645\_57, May 2004.
\bibitem{8} L. Zhang, L. B. Jack, and A. K. Nandi, “Fault detection using genetic programming,” Mech. Syst. Signal Process., Vol. 19, no. 2, pp. 271\_89, Mar. 2005.
\bibitem{9} A. Saxena, and A. Saad, “Evolving an artificial neural network classifier for condition monitoring of rotating mechanical systems,” Appl. Soft Computer., Vol. 7, no. 1, pp. 441\_54, Jan. 2007.
\bibitem{10}    B. Zhang, C. Sconyers, C. Byington, R. Patrick, M. Orchard, and G. Vachtsevanos, “A probabilistic fault detection approach: Application to bearing fault detection,” IEEE Trans. Ind. Electron., Vol. 58, no. 5,
pp. 2011\_8, May 2011.
\bibitem{11}    Y. Jianbo, “Local and nonlocal preserving projection for bearing defect classification and performance assessment,” IEEE Trans. Ind. Electron., Vol. 59, no. 5, pp. 2363\_76, May 2012.
\bibitem{12}     M. D. Prieto, G. Cirrincione, A. G Espinosa, J. A. Ortega, and H. Henao, “Bearing fault detection by a novel condition-monitoring scheme based on statistical-time features and neural networks,”IEEE Trans. Ind. Electron., Vol. 60, no. 8, pp. 3398\_407, Aug. 2013.

\end{thebibliography}

\section*{Note}\bf\large Manuscript length should be limited up to 10 pages including figures, tables, references, author’s bio and photo etc. After final checks, if the typeset manuscript exceeds 06 pages length, the author will be charged (after 06) per page @ Rs.1,000/- (for Indian Authors) and 50 USD (for Foreign Authors).
\end{document}
```

**The `IETEJR.cls` file is**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{IETEJR}[2016/02/09 V1.0 by Litun John]
%\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagefalse
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {210mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {250mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {11in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {14in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {10.5in}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}
   {\setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}}
\fi
\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@titlepagetrue}
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\@titlepagefalse}
\fi
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\fi
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\input{leqno.clo}}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      }%
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
}
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final}
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\setlength\parskip{0\p@ \@plus \p@}
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{3}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.5}
\if@twoside
  \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\subsectionmark##1{%
      \markright {%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\@ne
          \thesubsection\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}}
\else
  \def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \thesection\quad
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\fi
\def\ps@myheadings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble
    \let\subsectionmark\@gobble
    }
  \if@titlepage
  \newcommand\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\else
\newcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent
            \hb@xt@1.8em{%
                \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \bfseries\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\fi
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {section}
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
\newcommand\part{\par
   \addvspace{4ex}%
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \Large\bfseries \partname~\thepart
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \huge \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \huge \bfseries #1\par}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip 3ex
     \@afterheading}
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {1.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.0ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-2.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.0ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
\fi
\setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
\@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
\@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
\newenvironment{description}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries #1}
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      %\begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
     % \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        %\begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.2em}\vspace{\z@}}%
       % \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      %{\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\newenvironment{verse}
               {\let\\\@centercr
                \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
                        \itemindent   -1.5em%
                        \listparindent\itemindent
                        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
                        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\newenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent 1.5em%
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \rightmargin   \leftmargin
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\if@compatibility
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\z@
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    }
\else
\newenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
     \if@twoside\else
        \setcounter{page}\@ne
     \fi
    }
\fi
%keywords
\def\keywords{\par\addvspace\medskipamount{\rightskip=0pt plus1cm
\def\and{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\fi\
}\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces \par}}
\def\keywordname{{\bfseries Keywords:}} 
\newcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \renewcommand\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}
\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
\skip\@mpfootins = \skip\footins
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
\renewcommand \theequation {\@arabic\c@equation}
\newcounter{figure}
\renewcommand \thefigure {\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename~\thefigure}
\newenvironment{figure}
               {\@float{figure}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{figure*}
               {\@dblfloat{figure}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newcounter{table}
\renewcommand\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{\tablename~\thetable}
\newenvironment{table}
               {\@float{table}}
               {\end@float}
\newenvironment{table*}
               {\@dblfloat{table}}
               {\end@dblfloat}
\newlength\abovecaptionskip
\newlength\belowcaptionskip
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0\p@}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
\newcommand\@tocrmarg{2.55em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\newcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
       \if@compatibility
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand\listoftables{%
    \section*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    }
\let\l@table\l@figure
\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\newcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\let\@openbib@code\@empty
\newenvironment{theindex}
               {\if@twocolumn
                  \@restonecolfalse
                \else
                  \@restonecoltrue
                \fi
                \columnseprule \z@
                \columnsep 35\p@
                \twocolumn[\section*{\indexname}]%
                \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                        {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
                \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
                \let\item\@idxitem}
               {\if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@}
\newcommand\subitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{20\p@}}
\newcommand\subsubitem{\@idxitem \hspace*{30\p@}}
\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\newcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\newcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\newcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\newcommand\refname{REFERENCES}
\newcommand\indexname{Index}
\newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\newcommand\tablename{Table}
\newcommand\partname{Part}
\newcommand\appendixname{APPENDIX}
\newcommand\abstractname{ABSTRACT}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}
\setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
\setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\if@twoside
\else
  \raggedbottom
\fi
\if@twocolumn
  \twocolumn
  \sloppy
  \flushbottom
\else
  \onecolumn
\fi
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `article.cls'.
```

Hope this will help you to write your paper. Good luck for your paper.

Comment: Ehm, the [author instructions](http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=tijr20&page=instructions#.VrnNv0Mzox4) say *"Authors submitting PDF manuscripts must **also** submit either the Word or LaTeX source files, including all tables and figures as appropriate."* Is that not correct?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. But I found in the Manuscript Submission guidelines

**Manuscripts may be submitted in any standard format, including `Word, EndNote and PDF`. These files will be automatically converted into a PDF file for the review process. LaTeX files should be converted to PDF prior to submission because ScholarOne Manuscripts is not able to convert LaTeX files into PDFs directly.**

Comment: It will be better to take the help of the journal customer service regarding this confusion and to follow the guidelines they recommend.

Comment: That would be best. If you've submitted to that journal before without submitting the source then clearly the passage I quoted is wrong, and the journal  should be notified so they can update their instructions. (I won't be doing that though.)