# How to download "interact" class file for Taylor and Francis journals

Tags: document-classes

I wish to put a paper in the format of "IETE Technical review" (Taylor and Francis) latex format. From where can I download  "interact" class file. Also, since the journal gives no specific instructions about which template to use, can I use IEEE class template to write my paper ? I have gone through the link
[IETE journal of Research latex template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291930/iete-journal-of-research-latex-template) but instead of this, can I use IEEE template and send the paper ?

Comment: This is off-topic, but follow the instructions for authors.

Comment: The above link doesn't seem to be a correct template. Line spacing is too much in that. Instructions to authors have not given anything substantial. Can IEEE template be used to submit a paper then ?